# Maze maker for game using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I wold like some feedback on this mazefactory, it creatse a maze in a 2D array starting in the middle (the  treasure room) and creating new rooms until it reaches the outside of the maze. The maze is used in a textbased game.   The code works, I'm interested in learning.

```
public class MazeFactory {

    private Room[][] rooms;
    private int size;
    private Room outside;

    public MazeFactory(int size) {          
        this.size = size;
        rooms = new Room[size][size];           
    }

    public Maze LabyrinthBuilder() {            
        Room tresureRoom = createRoom(size/2, size/2, null, null);
        tresureRoom.setTresureRoom();
        System.out.println("TresureRoom: "+ tresureRoom.getX()+" "+tresureRoom.getY());         
        return new Maze(rooms, outside);
    }

    private Room createRoom(int x, int y, Room current, Wall wall) {
        if(x >= size || x < 0 || y >= size || y < 0) {
            return createOutside(current, wall);
        }           
        Room theRoom;           
        if(rooms[x][y] == null) { // If it is not a room there              
            theRoom = new Room(x, y);
            rooms[x][y] = theRoom;              
            // If there is not a room next to theRoom create a new wall, else use the wall from next room               
            if(y - 1 < 0 || rooms[x][y - 1] == null) {
                theRoom.setNorthWall(new Wall());
            } else {
                theRoom.setNorthWall(rooms[x][y - 1].getSouthWall());
            }
            if(y + 1 >= size || rooms[x][y + 1] == null) {
                theRoom.setSouthWall(new Wall());                   
            } else {
                theRoom.setSouthWall(rooms[x][y + 1].getNorthWall());
            }
            if(x - 1 < 0 || rooms[x - 1][y] == null) {
                theRoom.setEastWall(new Wall());
            } else {
                theRoom.setEastWall(rooms[x - 1][y].getWestWall());
            }
            if(x + 1 >= size || rooms[x + 1][y] == null) {
                theRoom.setWestWall(new Wall());
            } else {
                theRoom.setWestWall(rooms[x + 1][y].getEastWall());
            }               
        } else {
            theRoom = rooms[x][y];
        }
        addDoor(theRoom, x, y);
        return theRoom;
    }

    private void addDoor(Room current, int x, int y) {
        Wall wall;
        int rand = randomNumber();
        switch(rand) {
        case 0:
            wall = current.getNorthWall();
            y--;
            break;
        case 1:
            wall = current.getEastWall();
            x--;
            break;
        case 2:
            wall = current.getSouthWall();
            y++;
            break;
        case 3:
            wall = current.getWestWall();
            x++;
            break;
        default:
            wall = current.getNorthWall();
            y--;
        }
        if(wall.hasDoor()) {
            Room otherRoom = wall.getDoor().goThrough(current);
            createRoom(otherRoom.getX(), otherRoom.getY(), current, wall);
        } else {    
            wall.addDoor(new Door(current, createRoom(x, y, current, wall)));
        }           
    }       

    private Room createOutside(Room current, Wall currentWall) {            
        Room temp =  new Room(-1, -1);          
        if(current.getNorthWall() == currentWall) {
            temp.setSouthWall(currentWall);             
            temp.setNorthWall(new Wall());
            temp.setEastWall(new Wall());
            temp.setWestWall(new Wall());       
        }
        else if(current.getEastWall() == currentWall) {
            temp.setWestWall(currentWall);              
            temp.setNorthWall(new Wall());
            temp.setEastWall(new Wall());
            temp.setSouthWall(new Wall());
        }
        else if(current.getSouthWall() == currentWall) {                
            temp.setNorthWall(currentWall);             
            temp.setEastWall(new Wall());
            temp.setSouthWall(new Wall());
            temp.setWestWall(new Wall());
        }
        else if(current.getWestWall() == currentWall) {
            temp.setEastWall(currentWall);              
            temp.setNorthWall(new Wall());
            temp.setSouthWall(new Wall());
            temp.setWestWall(new Wall());           
        }
        temp.setOutside(true);
        outside = temp;
        return temp;            
    }       
    private int randomNumber() {
        return (int)(Math.random() * 10) / 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one minor readability issue would be to init the temp room with all walls and then later override the adjecting wall:

```
private Room createOutside(Room current, Wall currentWall) {            
    Room temp =  new Room(-1, -1); 
    //code from Room.createWalls():
    //temp.setSouthWall(new Wall());  
    //temp.setNorthWall(new Wall());
    //temp.setEastWall(new Wall());
    //temp.setWestWall(new Wall());        
    temp.createWalls();
    if(current.getNorthWall() == currentWall) {
        temp.setSouthWall(currentWall);             
    }
    else if(current.getEastWall() == currentWall) {
        temp.setWestWall(currentWall);              
    }
    else if(current.getSouthWall() == currentWall) {                
        temp.setNorthWall(currentWall);             
    }
    else if(current.getWestWall() == currentWall) {
        temp.setEastWall(currentWall);              
    }
    temp.setOutside(true);
    outside = temp;
    return temp;            
}
```

the same applies the method `private Room createRoom(...)`:

```
private Room createRoom(int x, int y, Room current, Wall wall) {
    if(x >= size || x < 0 || y >= size || y < 0) {
        return createOutside(current, wall);
    }
    Room theRoom;
    if(rooms[x][y] == null) { 
        rooms[x][y]= new Room(x, y) //FIXME skip local variable 'theRoom' - it's use is inkonsequent
        rooms[x][y].createWalls(); //see above, creates all four walls
        if(y - 1 < 0 || rooms[x][y - 1] == null) { 
            //rooms[x][y].setNorthWall(new Wall()); - can be skipped now
        }
        else {
            rooms[x][y].setNorthWall(rooms[x][y - 1].getSouthWall());
        }
        if(y + 1 >= size || rooms[x][y + 1] == null) {
            // rooms[x][y].setSouthWall(new Wall()); - can be skipped *again*
        } else {
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```

another minor issue would be to use directions instead of `int`s...

```
private final enum Direction {NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST};

private Direction getRandomDirection(){
    //untested code, it's straight from mind into CodeReview without compile check
    return new ArrayList<Direction>(Directions.values()).shuffle().get(0);
}

private void addDoor(Room current, int x, int y) {
    Wall wall;
    Direction dir = getRandomDirection();
    switch(dir) {
    case NORTH: 
        wall = current.getNorthWall();
        y--;
        break;
    case EAST: //and so on...
}
```

Comment: Since you always do this right after creating a new `Room` you might as well suggest to put it into the constructor of the `Room`. So a new `Room` will always be surrounded with 4 walls until one of them is replaced with a new connection.

Comment: i'm not sure if room is ever used in any other code pieces, but providing such a constructor would be indeed useful! @Imus